# Vagrant forwarding ssh from remote server

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I set up vagrant to run a vm on a host os.  What I would like to do is be able to ssh from other machines directly into the vagrant vm (ie, I shouldn't ssh into the host and then vagrant ssh, etc. into the vagrant vm).

Currently, I can ssh not using vagrant ssh from the host os using `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`.  However, if I run the same command (replacing 127.0.0.1 with the host's ip address), I get "ssh connect to host XXXXX port 2222: Connection refused."

I tried adding my own port forwarding rule to vagrant:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222
```

But that doesn't allow ssh connection from either the host machine or any other machine in the network.  Additionally, I spent a while with [config.ssh](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) in the vagrant docs.  I think that most of those parameters though specify what port the vagrant vm is running ssh on.

I really don't think this should be that difficult.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or what I should do differently to ssh into a vagrant vm from a remote server?

Comment: Is that port open in the firewall?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I can bind and listen to it with an example program I write and receive messages from other machines on it.

Comment: I was able to make it work by using a port number different than 2222. For instance this works with me:   
`config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.2"`   `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2022`

Comment: I had to change VirtualBox to use Bridged instead of Nat. Then I found the internal ip with `ifconfig` on the guest. After that `ssh-copy-id` from a remote to `vagrant@_ip_from_ifconfig_` after which I could login without a password.

Comment: @dmarr - could you please provide more details on your answer ? I really can't get what you did to make it work. thanks

Comment: @aspirinemaga sorry I didn't see the comment until now. Did you get it sorted?

Comment: @dmarr - no problem and yes a problem was solved, it's in accepted answer

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you don't want to change network to public you can override default port forwarding for ssh by this:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, host_ip: "0.0.0.0", id: "ssh", auto_correct: true
```

This will forward guest 22 port to 2222 on your host machine and will be available from any ip, so you can access it outside your local machine.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. Smallest and least disruptive change to do what you want to do.

Comment: This solution used to work for me, but when I installed Vagrant 1.9.7 on a new machine, I tried using this solution and it failed. I searched online and found that the solution was to replace `0.0.0.0` with `localhost` ([source](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395#issuecomment-290683377))

Comment: @AdamTaylor - your solution should be marked in the answer, it helped me to make it work. thanks

Answer (score 18):

Since v1.2.3 Vagrant port forwarding **by default binds with 127.0.0.1 so only local connections are allowed**.

You got "Connection refused" because the port forwarding was NOT binding to your network interfaces (e.g. eth0, wlan0). The port `2222` on your host is NOT even open to hosts in the same network (loopback interfaces not accessible to other hosts).

If you want to SSH directly to the Vagrant VM from a remote host (in the same LAN), the best and easiest way is to use Public Network (VirtualBox's Bridged networking mode).

Add the following to your `Vagrantfile` and do a `vagrant reload`.

It should bridge through one of the public network interfaces, you should be able to get the IP address after VM is up, `vagrant ssh` into it and run `ifconfig -a` or `ip addr` to get the IP address to ssh to from remote hosts.

Sample `Vagrantfile`

```
<!-- language: lang-rb -->

config.vm.network :public_network # 2nd interface bridged mode
```

or more advanced, you can set default network interface for public network

```
<!-- language: lang-rb -->

config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'
```

See more => [Public Network](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  Couple of questions: 1) This suggests that the guest and host will have different ip addresses, correct? 2) This requires a dhcp server to be pretty permissive about handing out ip addresses, right?  If I'm running on ec2 or other cloud providers, can I rely on that? (I'm pretty sure that I can't ...) 3) Why does your answer say that the remote machine must be in the same LAN?

Comment: I have my `config.vm.network` already set to public, but but I am still unable to to connect via ssh from an external client. `ssh -p 2222 vagrant@192.168.102.38` results in a `Connection refused`.

Comment: I shouldn't have specified the port; sshing works fine without specifying the port.

Answer (score 6):

You can also add another rule to `Vagrantfile` like the following:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1234, host: 22
```

Connect to Vagrant with the default port (2222) and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then add below `Port 22` the port previously configured as 'guest', resulting:

```
...
Port 22 #Uncomment this line if it's commented
Port 1234
....
```

Finally, restart the ssh daemon or do `vagrant reload` (if you edited `Vagrantfile` while the VM was running you have to reload it) and now you can connect to Vagrant using 'host' port (22 in my case) from outside the host computer.

You can't remove the default port, because Vagrant would hang when starting up.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `vagrant share --ssh`

Vagrant now has a service for registering a Vagrant VM
for remote SSH access automatically.

See here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/ssh.html

You call `vagrant share --ssh`.
This generates an SSH key (encrypted and password-protected), 
uploads it to a Hashicorp server,
and returns a silly global box name (e.g. "rambunctious-deer-3496").
Then everybody who

- has a Hashicorp [Atlas account](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/atlas.html)
- knows the box name,
- knows the password for the key, and
- has Vagrant installed(!)

can perform remote SSH to the box via 
`vagrant connect --ssh BOXNAME`.
Vagrant takes care of all the admin stuff behind the scenes (here are [some details](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/vagrant/shares)).

Works as advertised.
I *guess* this will even work if the Vagrant host (not merely the VM) is behind a NAT.

Limitations:

- `vagrant share` sessions expire ([currently after 8 hours](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/vagrant/shares))
- expect some latency, because all traffic is (presumably)
  routed through the Altas server
- I have seen my remote connections close (for no obvious reason)
  after I had not used them for maybe 15 minutes.