# Kafka producer creation from command prompt giving broker disconnected error

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a Kafka producer from command prompt using below command and getting this error message. This was working fine on my laptop but failing when I tried the same on a virtual machine. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*C:\kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

> [2020-10-31 10:53:55,832] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker vagrant-10:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)*

Answer (score 0):

Your Kafka VM has advertised.listeners including `vagrant-10:9092`

Your host likely cannot resolve this DNS name

Fix your listeners configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this- Under the bin location

```
./kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic your topic name
```

Comment: I think, that problem is Vagrant forwarding kafka port from remote server/local machine.
Review the following discusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204358/vagrant-forwarding-ssh-from-remote-server